# Selenium Navigating Through Outlook Mail Login (Headless Driver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium and Python 3.9 to navigate through the Outlook mail login. The goal is to reach the main inbox page after logging in successfully. I am using a chrome driver and am experiencing errors when running the script below to navigate through Outlook's login. When I run a headless driver or simply minimize the window without going headless, the **login page seems to freeze before clicking the 'Next' button on the password page** no matter how long I set the timeout time. Is there a solution to this?

The code below can be tested after you specify your Outlook login username, password, and the path to where the Chrome driver was downloaded:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
import time

# -- Login Credentials
o_username = ' OUTLOOK LOGIN USERNAME '
o_password = ' OUTLOOK LOGIN USERNAME '

# -- Headless Driver (Ideal)
#o_options = Options()
#o_options.headless = True
#o_driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=o_options, executable_path=r' PATH TO DRIVER DOWNLOAD ')

# -- Minimized Window (Not ideal, but accepted)
o_driver = webdriver.Chrome(r' PATH TO DRIVER DOWNLOAD ')
o_driver.minimize_window()

o_driver.get('https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox')

# -- Fill username and click next
WebDriverWait(o_driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'i0116'))).send_keys(o_username)
WebDriverWait(o_driver, 10,(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'idSIButton9'))).click()

time.sleep(3)

# -- Fill password and click next
WebDriverWait(o_driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'i0118'))).send_keys(o_password)
WebDriverWait(o_driver, 10, (NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'idSIButton9'))).click()

try:
    # -- Detect HTML element only on main inbox page
    WebDriverWait(o_driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'Pivot29-Tab0')))
except:
    # -- Handle the 'Stay Logged In?' page and click 'Yes'
    WebDriverWait(o_driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'idSIButton9'))).click()
    time.sleep(3)

    # -- Detect the element on main inbox page
    # -- ERROR OCCURS HERE BY TIMEOUT BECAUSE PAGE IS STILL STUCK ON PASSWORD FILL-IN PAGE
    WebDriverWait(o_driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'Pivot29-Tab0')))

# -- Main Inbox Loaded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the GUI to automate emails is notoriously slow and overly difficult. A lot of mail clients don't like GUI automation.

A better way to do it is via the mail protocol itself.

There are libraries for that and lots of [guides](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/reading-emails-in-python). This can get you started:

```py
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header


# account
username = "email@domain.com"
password = "password!"

imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
imap.login(username, password)

status, messages = imap.select("INBOX")
messages = int(messages[0]) # this is how many mails you have
print ('# emails in inbox:', messages)

# count down as the highest number is latest email
# this loop is top 5 emails
for i in range(messages, messages-5, -1):
    res, msg = imap.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
    for response in msg:
        if isinstance(response, tuple):
            # parse a bytes email into a message object
            msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
            # decode the email subject
            subject, encoding = decode_header(msg["Subject"])[0]
            From, encoding = decode_header(msg.get("From"))[0]
            print("From: " + From + " -> Subject :" +subject)

imap.close()
imap.logout()
```

I won't share all 5 of my emails but this is s test one i sent for the demo:

> From: Richard Edwards this.is.my.mail@removed.com -> Subject :Hello
> World

That's how my mail looks:
[image: emails]

You can get your imap address from your webmail settings.

Comment: the body text of the email I am trying to extract is not retrieved using the code you provided. This may be because the email contains a verification code as a 2-step verification login for this external site. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @Kevin did you read the guide in the link? - my code is to get you started. It's not attempting to get the body of the email.

Comment: Ah yes, just a little bit of digging into the documentation, this solution worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've scripted outlook before and ran into this same issue. Hiding the fact that I'm using an automated browser fixed it. Here's some code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
o_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe", options=options)
```